# Using View Width does not properly size subsequent uilabel using swift in xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

Ok, so I have simplified my problem down to its most basic form.  I have a view whose width is 0.7 times its main view.  I am programmatically adding a UILabel into that view and I am trying to make it the same size.  I am then printing out the size into 2 views for debugging purposes.

Here is my code:

```
  let test = trackerView.bounds.size.width

    let testLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,test,30))
    testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    trackerView.addSubview(testLabel)


    lblStageDescription.text = testLabel.bounds.width.description
    lblTime.text = trackerView.bounds.width.description
```

And this is what my simulator looks like

[image: Picture of the broken sizing problem I am having]

The blue is the TestLabel and that white part underneath of it is the trackerView.

Then the 2 numbers 420.0 are where the widths are printed out.

Is there something different about the sizing for a UILabel vs a UIView?  Am I missing something?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What method is the code in? Are you using auto layout? What device are you testing on? If it's an iPhone, 420 points is wider than a view controller's view. Can only speculate that you've used auto layout and then added the view in viewdidload before constraints were applied. Causing trackerview to get resized. Try moving your code to viewdidappear or viewdidlayoutsubviews.

```
let testLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,test,30))
    testLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    trackerView.addSubview(testLabel)
```

This is the code that is creating the label. I'm not sure about the label you created in IB but this is a declaration with initializer, so your code is interacting with it and by default has no constraints. You can set `trackerView.clipToBounds = true` so it's subviews won't extend past it's bounds, but the label will be clipped as well.

Comment: Yes Autolayout is checked.  The View however, was not added in viewDidLoad.  I dragged and dropped it and then added the equal width constraint.  Then changed the multiplier of that constraint to 0.7.  

I tried putting that code into the viewDidAppear and viewDidLayoutSubviews(It was in viewDidLoad) and nothing changed.  I am using an Iphone 6s simulator...but it does the same thing on any of the simulators.

Comment: I did not notice before but the labels display 262.5 points for the width when the code is in viewDidLayoutSubviews...but the label is still off the screen.  This is so strange

Comment: I meant the view was created with the UI.  Yes obviously the Label is created with those lines of code.  clipToBounds would clip off the edge right?  I need it to scale correctly.

Comment: ok I made a mistake here.  I left the old code in viewDidLoad and so I could not see the blue label that was created in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  It worked in viewDidLayoutSubviews.  Thanks!!!

Comment: This is not strange this is what is expect. In viewDidLoad frames will be set to their canvas size  in IB letter in the lifecycle is when the layout engine does it magic and updates the frames hence why the frame went from 600*0.70 = 420.0 to 375 *0.70 = 262.5